# .NET Core Identity and Simple Injector. Crosswire not working

Tags: asp.net-core, simple-injector, asp.net-core-identity

I am using simple injector (4.8.1) on a project that uses asp.net core identity. I tried to crosswise UserManager but I got an error saying
 `` No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Tenancy.Core.Domain.AppUser]' has been registered." ``
the SimpleInjectorConfig class is:

```cs
public static class SimpleInjectorConfig
{
    private static Container _container;

    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config,
        IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _container = new Container();

        _container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        _container.ConfigureCore(config, env);

        _container.RegisterInitializer<BaseApiController>(controller =>
        {
            controller.Mediator = _container.GetInstance<IMediator>();
        });

        services.AddSingleton(_container);
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddLogging();
        // Sets up the basic configuration that for integrating Simple Injector with
        // ASP.NET Core by setting the DefaultScopedLifestyle, and setting up auto
        // cross wiring.
        services.AddSimpleInjector(_container, options =>
        {
            // AddAspNetCore() wraps web requests in a Simple Injector scope and
            // allows request-scoped framework services to be resolved.
            options
                .AddAspNetCore()
                .AddControllerActivation();
            options.AddLogging();
            options.CrossWire<UserManager<AppUser>>();
        });
    }

    public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSimpleInjector(_container);
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        }
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        _container.Verify();
    }
}
```

and I called it in my Startup.cs file

```cs
 public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment _env { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        SimpleInjectorConfig.ConfigureServices(services, _configuration, _env);
        CorsConfig.ConfigureServices(services);
        DatabaseConfig.ConfigureServices(services, _configuration);
        MvcConfig.ConfigureServices(services);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        SimpleInjectorConfig.Configure(app, env);
        CorsConfig.Configure(app, _configuration);
        MvcConfig.Configure(app);
    }
}
```

The configurations have their own class and called in the Startup called in the Startup class just to keep it clean, SimpleInjectorConfig is the config class for simple injector.

Comment: Please show more relevant parts of your configuration. Currently, your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: @Steven I made an update. hope it's better now. Thanks

Comment: Are you missing an `AddIdentity` call? Generally speaking, there is no need to explicitly call `CrossWire` as Simple Injector's `AddSimpleInjector` does this for you under the covers. However, the requested type must still exist in .NET Core configuration system.

Comment: Arrgh...How could I have missed that. Thanks @Steven. That was the issue.  `Add Identity` .